# Create array from given array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

**Is it possible to create an Array from another Array?**
*Lang: Ruby on Rails*

#### Case

Workers are entitled to fill in their own work hours. Sometimes they forget to do it. This is what I want to tackle. In the end, I want an Array with time codes of periods the worker forgot to register his hours.

```
timecodes = [201201, 201202, 201203, 201204, 201205, 201206, 201207, 201208, 201209, 201210, 201211, 201212, 201213, 201301, 201302, 201304, 201305, 201306, ...]
```

Worker works from 201203 to 201209 with us.

```
timecards = [201203, 201204, 201205, 201207, 201208, 201209]
```

As you see, he forgot to register 201206.

#### What I want to do

```
# Create Array from timecode on start to timecode on end
worked_with_us = [201203, 201204, 201205, 201206, 201207, 201208, 201209]  
   #=> This is the actual problem, how can I automate this?

forgot_to_register = worked_with_us.?????(timecards)
forgot_to_register = worked_with_us - timecards  # Thanks Zwippie
   #=> [201206]
```

Now I know which period the worker forgot to register his hours.

#### All together

1. How can I create an Array from another Array, giving a start and end value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subtract arrays with `-` (minus):

```
[1, 2, 3] - [1, 3] = [2]
```

To build an array with years/months, this can be done with a [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html), but this only works if you build an array for each year, something like:

```
months = (2012..2013).map do |year|
  ("#{year}01".."#{year}12").to_a.collect(&:to_i)
end.flatten

  => [201201, 201202, 201203, 201204, 201205, 201206, 201207, 201208, 201209, 201210, 201211, 201212, 201301, 201302, 201303, 201304, 201305, 201306, 201307, 201308, 201309, 201310, 201311, 201312]
```

And for the function to create those ranges dynamically:

```
def month_array(year_from, year_to, month_from=1, month_to=12)
  (year_from..year_to).map do |year|
    # Correct from/to months
    mf = year_from == year ? month_from : 1
    mt = year_to == year ? month_to : 12

    (mf..mt).map do |month|
      ("%d%02d" % [year, month]).to_i
    end
  end.flatten
end
```

Update: You wanted other input parameters for this method, but I hope you can work that out yourself. :)

Comment: Thank you, I was totally thinking to complicated! Do you have any ideas on the first issue?

Comment: Thank you, I achieved that with `(2012..2013).each do |y| { (1..13).each do |p| { timecodes.push "#{y}#{"02d" % p}" } }`. I want to create an array based on this array. So I can give the start value and the stop value and create an array from those. Let's say: `start = 201210`, `stop = 201303`. The Array should be: `worked_with_us = [201210, 201211, 201212, 201213, 201301, 201302, 201303]`

Comment: Ok, I added a method to do that.